# When a .dll asks for source code in debug mode

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, debugging, nhibernate, dll

Is there something wrong with the .dll file? Shouldn't it just consider the code as closed source since it's all byte code and try NOT to step through it? Is there any way to make this possible?

For example, I have an ASP.net MVC 3 project which is using both Fluent NHibernate and NHibernate. Regardless of which version I use, I can't debug what is happening without having actual access to the source code.

This, I believe poses a problem, for I've installed the necessary binaries to build the project, and therefore SHOULD be able to just debug and get the necessary information available on my variables without stepping through the code itself. If this is not the case (which it isn't, obviously), what can I do about it?

Note: my whole goal here is to see if it's possible to debug my code WITHOUT requiring the source files, as I have the .dll installed, and therefore shouldn't require the source to view the data that variables hold on the stack.

Comment: I don't know if it's just me, but I got confused by your question: Do you or do you not want to be able to step through code  from third-party libraries?

Comment: In the first paragraph it sounds like you want to not step into a DLL, and then in the second paragraph you say you want to. It's remarkably unclear what you're actually asking here.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion: I edited for clarity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check to see if [Just My Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5e30exc.aspx) is enabled in your debug options and settings.

From above link:

> Sometimes, while you are debugging, you might want to look at only the code you have written and ignore other code, such as system calls. You can do this with Just My Code debugging. Just My Code hides non-user code so that it does not appear in the debugger windows. When you step, the debugger steps through any non-user code but does not stop in it.

Comment: @Mark I wish I could give you all my points. You have saved me much headache and heartache.